# Angular 1.5.5 md-autocomplete validation not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have Angular 1.5.5 and I'm using md-autocomplete and when I add `required` to my markup, it is marking input as invalid when it is invalid, but when it is valid, it does not update my `ng-form`, so my form is still marked as invalid because of it.

Angular material: v1.1.5

Any solution how to overcome this?

**EDIT - Resolved**

So, the problem is because in the example from angular site, the markup does not contain explicit `name` attribute, it have just `md-input-name`, but for some reason with only that it does not work well when it is nested within the `ng-form` so the solution is just to add `name` attribute.

Once I did that, works like a charm.

Comment: Which is your angular material version?

Comment: It is version 1.1.5